# Extract a field from a column (in json) and Concat them in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, concatenation

I want to extract and concat a field in a json column .

I have a table with two field :

- id
- JsonColumn

In the json Column i can have x object which contains 2 fields  (`Name` and `Type`)

For Example, in my table I can have :
[image]

What i want to do is to extract and concat the field `Name` in a json colum.
So i will have :
[image]

Don't hesitate to share your opinion.
(I was thinking about a big loop with openJson but i fear that the query will be very long after that).

Comment: First idea: Extract in one CTE all JSON names with id. Second CTE do a recursive concatenation by id. Output then groups by id with concatenated names?

Comment: I'm not an expert with relational databases, but why are you even storing JSON in a database? The idea of a relational database is to store (more or less) one value per cell / column.

Comment: What is your SQL server version?

Comment: Thx for your replies.
Knut : I am not sure to see the idea about extract the json name in a cte (Put the json column in a viariable and use OpenJson for each row?)

Arun : SQL server Developer 2016 with the SP2 updated

Comment: @MoonLightFlower Yes. First part is to extract the JSON with OUTER APPLY AND WITH structuring (lots of examples here on SO). Convert from semi structured to relational. Second part is to convert the relational part back into the desired concatenation using recursive techniques. Third is the output of the desired output.

Comment: @Lino JSON is a standard for data interchange and uses less space than XML. Using JSON in a table allows access with SQL instead having to use third party tools outside of the database (which is also an option to get the data into relational format). Thus JSON is useful for REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON content using `OPENSJON()` to extract the `"Name"` key and then aggregate the values. For SQL Server 2016 you need to use `FOR XML PATH` for aggregation.

Table:

```
SELECT Id, JsonColumn
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, '[{"Name": "Matthew", "Type":"Public"}, {"Name": "Rachel", "Type":"Private"}]'),
   (2, '[{"Name": "Sample", "Type":"Private"}]')
) v (Id, JsonColumn)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Id, 
   Name = STUFF(
      (
      SELECT ',' + Name 
      FROM OPENJSON(JsonColumn) WITH (Name varchar(100) '$.Name')
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, ''
   )
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
Id  JsonColumn
------------------
1   Matthew,Rachel
2   Sample
```

Comment: do you mind if I add your STUFF example into my demo code and answer?

Comment: @KnutBoehnert, feel free to use this part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rough approach (currently not enough time for me to provide working SQL to code).
To do it in one step (best as view) use the CTE approach to stagger the steps. This generates more code and over time allows easier amendments. It is a trade off.

1. *Recursive approach*

First step:

Extract relational records with ID and names. Use OPENJSON WITH a defined table structure where only the Name is extracted (rest can be ignored or left as additional JSON).

Second step:

Use the output from first step and turn into recursive concatenation. Using a variable to concatenate to forces the use of a procedure. Doing it in a view requires definition of anchor and end conditions. Not quite sure on this as it is tricky.

In a CTE part this requires an anchor element union'ed with all other elements. In effect this groups by the selected key field(s).

Third step:

Output of the finished recursion by key field(s).

Quick demo code

```
DECLARE
  @Demo TABLE
(
  id_col      tinyint identity(1,1),
  dsc_json    nvarchar(max)
)
;

INSERT INTO 
  @Demo
(
  dsc_json
)
SELECT N'[{"Name":"Celery","Type":"Vegetable"}, {"Name":"Tomato","Type":"Fruit"}]'
UNION
SELECT N'[{"Name":"Potato","Type":"Vegetable"}]'
UNION
SELECT N'[{"Name":"Cherry","Type":"Fruit"}, {"Name":"Apple","Type":"Fruit"}]'
;

SELECT
  *
FROM
  @Demo
;

-- extract JSON
SELECT
  demo.id_col,
  jsond.dsc_name,
  Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name ASC ) AS val_row_asc,
  Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name DESC ) AS val_row_desc
FROM
  @Demo AS demo
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( demo.dsc_json )
    WITH
    (
      dsc_name   nvarchar(100) '$.Name'
    ) AS jsond
;

WITH
  cte_json
(
  id_col,
  dsc_name,
  val_row_asc,
  val_row_desc
)
AS
(
  SELECT
    demo.id_col,
    jsond.dsc_name,
    Cast( Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name ASC ) AS int ) AS val_row_asc,
    Cast( Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name DESC ) AS int ) AS val_row_desc
  FROM
    @Demo AS demo
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( demo.dsc_json )
      WITH
      (
        dsc_name   nvarchar(100) '$.Name'
      ) AS jsond
),
  cte_concat
(
  id_col,
  dsc_names,
  val_row_asc,
  val_row_desc
)
AS
( -- anchor first
  -- - emtpy string per ID
  SELECT
    anchor.id_col,
    Cast( N'' AS nvarchar(500) ) AS names,
    Cast( 0 AS int) AS val_row_asc,
    Cast( -1 AS int ) AS val_row_desc
  FROM
    cte_json AS anchor
  WHERE -- anchor criteria
      val_row_asc = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    anchor.id_col,
    Cast( anchor.dsc_names + N', ' + element.dsc_name AS nvarchar(500) ) AS names,
    element.val_row_asc,
    element.val_row_desc
  FROM 
    cte_json AS element
    INNER JOIN cte_concat AS anchor
      ON  anchor.id_col = element.id_col
      AND anchor.val_row_asc = element.val_row_asc -1
)
SELECT
  cte.id_col,
  Right( cte.dsc_names, Len( cte.dsc_names ) -2 ) AS dsc_names,
  cte.val_row_desc
FROM 
  cte_concat AS cte
WHERE -- only latest result
    cte.val_row_desc = 1
ORDER BY
    cte.id_col ASC
;
```

The additional row numbers allow:

- define start and end point for the recursive connection = val_row_asc
- define "definition" of latest result = val_row_desc

2. *Stuff ... for XML Path*

This approach works on all versions and is much easier to read than the recursive part thanks to Zhorov's answer. Works on the base laid by the first part of the code above (or just straight afterwards).

```
WITH
  cte_json
(
  id_col,
  dsc_name,
  val_row_asc,
  val_row_desc
)
AS
(
  SELECT
    demo.id_col,
    jsond.dsc_name,
    Cast( Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name ASC ) AS int ) AS val_row_asc,
    Cast( Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name DESC ) AS int ) AS val_row_desc
  FROM
    @Demo AS demo
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( demo.dsc_json )
      WITH
      (
        dsc_name   nvarchar(100) '$.Name'
      ) AS jsond
)
SELECT
  cte_outer.id_col,
  Stuff( 
      ( SELECT 
          ',' + cte_inner.dsc_name 
        FROM 
          cte_json AS cte_inner 
        WHERE 
            cte_inner.id_col = cte_outer.id_col 
        FOR XML PATH('') 
      ), 1, 1, '' 
    ) AS dsc_names
FROM 
  cte_json AS cte_outer
GROUP BY
  cte_outer.id_col
;
```

3. *String_agg*

This approach only works with SQL Server 2017 onwards. It is a continuation to the code above.

```
WITH
  cte_json
(
  id_col,
  dsc_name,
  val_row_asc,
  val_row_desc
)
AS
(
  SELECT
    demo.id_col,
    jsond.dsc_name,
    Cast( Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name ASC ) AS int ) AS val_row_asc,
    Cast( Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY demo.id_col ORDER BY jsond.dsc_name DESC ) AS int ) AS val_row_desc
  FROM
    @Demo AS demo
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( demo.dsc_json )
      WITH
      (
        dsc_name   nvarchar(100) '$.Name'
      ) AS jsond
)
SELECT
  cte.id_col,
  String_agg( cte.dsc_name, ',' ) AS dsc_names
FROM 
  cte_json AS cte
GROUP BY
  cte.id_col
;
```

Comment: Thx for your tips too :)